# Export/analyze Facebook messages

Tags: facebook

I'm looking for a way to export my Facebook/Messenger messages in a clean way, like a PDF, and that would be able to do some statistics on it, like counting number of messages etc.

I am aware of the possibility to create an archive of my account, which includes messages in a HTML file, so the app may work using this file.

Answer (score 1):

Not a ready rolled solution but you have a couple of options using [Python](https://www.python.org/):

- You can use the Facebook graph API via the [SDK](http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) *You will have to get a [token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)* to directly query Facebook for the data that you need.
- You can download you data as a zip archive and then use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the html to extract the data.

Once you have got the data, using either of the mechanisms above you can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to produce statistics, graphs, summaries, etc.

If you use a [Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.org/) to do all or some of the above you will be able to arrange things into a nice report and then convert it to a PDF document.

All of the above items are Free, Gratis & Open Source.  There is a lot of online material available to help you get what you would like from them.